# Undefined index: categories work around

Tags: php, mysqli

i m geting this error in my code

Undefined index: categories

```
Notice: Undefined index: categories in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\admin\products.php on line 14
```

this is line 14

```
$child_id = $product['categories'];
```

and this is whole code

```
<?php 
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project/core/init.php';
include 'includes/head.php';
include 'includes/navigation.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE deleted = 0";
$presults = $db->query($sql);
?>
<h2 class="text-centre" style="text-align: center;">Products</h2><hr>
<table class="table table-boedered table-condensed table-striped">
<thead><th></th><th>Products</th><th>Price</th><th>Category</th><th>Featured</th><th>Sold</th></thead>
<tbody>
    <?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($presults)): 
          // Trying to display the parent category for every product
               $child_id = $product['categories'];
               $catSql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = '$child_id'";
               $result = mysqli_query($db, $catSql);
               $child = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
               $parentID = $child['parent_id'];
               $pSql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = '$parentID'";
               $presult = mysqli_query($db, $pSql);
               $parent = mysqli_fetch_assoc($presult);
               $category = $parent['category'] . '-' . $child['category'];
               // Idea for future. Will have nested categories. Only display immediate parent category of product
          ?>
     <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="Products.php?edit=<?=$Product['id'];?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-defualt"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
            <a href="Products.php?delete=<?=$Product['id'];?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-defualt"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
        </td>
        <td><?=$product['title']; ?></td>
        <td><?=money($product['price']);?></td>
        <td><?=$category; ?></td>
        <td>o</td>
     </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</tbody>
</table>



 <?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>﻿
```

What is this mean and how to work around it

thanks in advance

Comment: you sure that column even exists? what's the db schema for the table?

Comment: btw, you don't have a very good track record here on Stack

Answer (score 0):

That seems to indicate your `Product` table doesn't have a `categories` column.
Verify by adding this, before line 14:

```
var_dump($product);
```

You will then see the `$product` array you can work with, and you can verify where you should get the category ID from.

Comment: Bonne chance de voir le p'tit check en vert ;-) The OP doesn't have a very good track record; dommage. Eh bin... quoi faire(?).

Comment: thank you sir works perfect noe